# Angular 2+ ngOnInit() not being called if router navigates to current route( with new query params) from itself

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my `home.component.ts`, my `ngOnInit` method is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngoninitcalled");
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params:Params) => {
        let refresh = params['refresh'];
        if(refresh){
            // do something refreshing
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `customFunction`

```
customFunction(email: string, username:string) {
    // do something custom
    this.router.navigate([''],{queryParams: {refresh:true}});     
}
```

The '' route redirects to `home.component.ts` or HomeComponent(snippet of whose are above).

On checking console logs, I see that when HomeComponent is called with refresh param from other components(via `this.router.navigate([''], {queryParams: {refresh:true}}`), ngOnInit() is called. But if its called from HomeComponent itself(as in above code), ngOnInit() is not called.

So is it the expected behavior and can I safely call `this.ngOnInit()` after the `router.navigate` in my custom function to invoke `ngOnInit()` manually(assuming `ngOnInit` will never be called if HomeComponent is redirected to from itself)?

Comment: you cannot call this.ngOnInit, because it called automatically only one times when initialization component, you can resolve it to create your function and call it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behavior that the ngOnInit is not called when navigating to the same component with different parameters.

But you should *not* call ngOnInit manually.

The subscription will get notified each time the parameters change. So code within the subscribe method will execute each time. You don't need to call ngOnInit.

Try it by moving your console.log within the subscribe.

Comment: Hey @DeborahK, finally caught you on stackoverflow :) Loved your answer as much as your pluralsight course on angular 2. Thanks again!!

Comment: not yet, but would be worth seeing. I will definitely have a look!